# Netty IO send Message to Client

Tags: java, class, methods, netty, server

how can I send a message from the Server to the Client using Netty?
I know you can do it like

```
  for (Channel c : channels1) {
    c.writeAndFlush("TEXT \r\n");
  }
```

but it is only usable from inside the ChatServerHandler Class. Is there a method to send Messages to the Client or how can I make a method which I can call like for example

```
sendMessageToServer("MESSAGE");

void sendMessageToServer(String message) {
final ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);
      for (Channel c : channels) {
        c.writeAndFlush("TEXT \r\n");
      }
}
```

? If I get the Channels like in ChatServerHandler using

```
final ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);
```

I get a Channel size of 0.

Answer (score 0):

`final ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);`
This constructs a new `ChannelGroup` with nothing inside.

You should have a class extends `SimpleChannelInboundHandler<?>`.
The `channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext chc)` method is called when something is connected. Simply add `Channel` instance to your `channels` by `channels.add(chc.channel());`
You may have to make your `ChannelGroup` public so it can be acessed everywhere. Good luck.

Comment: I already have the channelAdded method and I add the channels to the group, and after a client connects the group has a size of 1, but I don't know how to use it to getthe channels to send a message to. The ChannelGroup can't be accessed from outside because I get a static error or something like that.

Comment: That's what I said. You need to make your `ChannelGroup` public. Try to make it `public static` so that you can access it directly. `public static ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);`